# NoClassDefFoundError using jna.jar and platform.jar

Tags: java, swing, internet-explorer-9, java-native-interface, jna

I need to find a way to change the settings of proxy on the IE 9.

I know a way directly in the reg., but ie9 doesn't refresh after I set them.
I tried to use another solution with jna:

[Invoke WinInet Functions Used Java + JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501787/invoke-wininet-functions-used-java-jna)

In my case I use only:

```
System.out.println("Set refreshed...");

if (!WinInet.INSTANCE.InternetSetOption(
    hInternet, WinInet.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, (Pointer) null, len)) {
        System.out.println("InternetSetOption failed!:"
            + Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
```

but I get this error:

```
Set refreshed...
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
    com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef$DWORD
```

I downloaded the lib jars from here:

http://java.net/projects/jna/downloads/directory/3.3.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

makesure you have `platform-3.4.0.jar` and `jna-3.4.0.jar` in your classpath

Comment: For now i use 3.3.0, i going to get 3.4.0 from: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.dev.jna/platform/3.4.0

Comment: And make sure that those are the *only* [JNA](http://github.com/twall/jna) jars in your class path.  There are other tools and environments that make use of JNA, so there may be more than one version present.  Note also that JNA is no longer hosted on java.net but is now on [github](http://github.com/twall/jna).

Comment: I checked, I use only one file and the ver. for platform and for the jna is the same.Could you give me a link to be sure that i download the right version.

Comment: [jna.jar](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.5.1/jna-3.5.1.jar) and [platform.jar](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.5.1/platform-3.5.1.jar), and make sure you recompile all dependencies.

Comment: when i put the libs in my lib folder, then i set them in my Java Build Path, I get the same error:                                           Set refreshed...
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/j
na/platform/win32/WinDef$DWORD

Comment: I am still at the same problem, what is the best practice that i need to do in this case?